# Get same nth day of the month in x number of months

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am needing some help converting a function from access vba to vb.net.
The script generates a new date, based on the date entered, and the number of months to be added.
“If today is the second Tuesday in March, what will be the second Tuesday in 4 months?”

```
Public Function NdNwk(dType As String, _
        dtSpan As Integer, sDate As Date) As Variant
'  This Function RETURNS the DAY of WHICH WEEK
'  (e.g. Second Tuesday of the Month).
'  FUNCTIONS to be passed to Variables:
'  gtDoW: Day of the WEEK of the START DATE.
'  (1 for Sunday, 2 for Monday, etc.)
'  gtWoM: WEEK of the MONTH of the START DATE.
'  (1 for First, 2 for Second, etc.)
'  gtDSTdt: Desired DATE
'  (generated by the [DateAdd] Function).

'  CALL EXAMPLE: If TODAY is Tuesday, March 10, 2020, 
‘  (second Tuesday of March), then using
'  NdNwk(m, 2, #5/21/2020#)
'  Would generate the DATE 5/12/2020,
'  As the SECOND TUESDAY of MAY.

    Dim gtDSTdt As Date, gtWoM As Integer, gtDoW As Integer
    Dim iLoop As Integer, iPick As Integer, dstDTdom As Date

    gtDoW = Weekday(sDate)
    gtWoM = (Int((Day(sDate) - 1) / 7) + 1)
    gtDSTdt = DateAdd(dType, dtSpan, sDate)

    For iLoop = 1 To Day(DateSerial(Year(gtDSTdt), _
                    Month(gtDSTdt) + 1, 0))

        dstDTdom = DateSerial(Year(gtDSTdt), _
                Month(gtDSTdt), iLoop)

        If Weekday(dstDTdom, 1) = gtDoW Then
            iPick = iPick + 1
            If iPick = gtWoM Then
                NdNwk = dstDTdom
                Exit Function
            End If

        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Any and all help is appreciated here.

Comment: See whether you can use something like this: `Dim baseDay = New Date(2020, 5, 12)
Dim firstDayInFourMonths = New Date(baseDay.Year, baseDay.Month, 1).AddMonths(4) Dim secondTuesdayInFourMonths = firstDayInFourMonths.AddDays(Enumerable.Range(0, Date.DaysInMonth(firstDayInFourMonths.Year, firstDayInFourMonths.Month) - 1).Where(Function(i) firstDayInFourMonths.AddDays(i).DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Tuesday).Skip(1).First())`, so you can give a hint of what tools you have avalable.

Comment: I think converting vba to vb.net is off topic here as well as converting vb.net to c# ;) Do you have some specific question/issue you wanna ask? Did you tried something by yourself? Please, show us an effort that you did something, because otherwise you just delegating your work to others and this is not cool.

Answer (score 0):

I used several of the properties and methods of the .net `DateTime` structure. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netcore-3.1

The arithmetic in the Function used the `Mod` operator which returns the remainder of the division. The integer division (the formard slash `\`) returns the integer portion of the division.

The only other thing that might be unfamiliar is the interpolated string, a string starting with `$`"". This allows you to directly embed variables in the string surround by `{ }`.

```
Private Function NdNwk(InputDate As Date, MonthsAhead As Integer) As String
    Dim newDate As Date
    Dim DofWeek = InputDate.DayOfWeek
    Dim Day = InputDate.Day
    Dim OfInputMonth As Integer
    If Day Mod 7 = 0 Then
        OfInputMonth = Day \ 7
    Else
        OfInputMonth = (Day \ 7) + 1
    End If
    Dim TempDate = InputDate.AddMonths(MonthsAhead)
    Dim NewMonth = TempDate.Month
    Dim NewYear = TempDate.Year
    Dim FirstWeek As Date
    Dim NewDay As Integer
    For d = 1 To 7
        FirstWeek = New Date(TempDate.Year, TempDate.Month, d)
        If FirstWeek.DayOfWeek = DofWeek Then
            NewDay = d
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Dim DaysToAdd = (OfInputMonth - 1) * 7
    newDate = New Date(NewYear, NewMonth, NewDay).AddDays(DaysToAdd)
    Dim NewDateString = $"{newDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")} is the {GetOrdinalString(OfInputMonth)} {DofWeek} of {TempDate.ToString("MMMM")}, {TempDate.Year}"
    Return NewDateString
End Function

Private Function GetOrdinalString(input As Integer) As String
    Dim output As String
    Select Case input
        Case 1
            output = "1St"
        Case 2
            output = "2nd"
        Case 3
            output = "3rd"
        Case 4
            output = "4th"
        Case 5
            output = "5th"
        Case Else
            output = ""
    End Select
    Return output
End Function
```

Usage...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim InputDate As Date
    Dim MonthsToAdd As Integer
    If Not Date.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, InputDate) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid date in Date")
        Return
    End If
    If Not Integer.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, MonthsToAdd) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number in Months To Add")
        Return
    End If

    Dim d = NdNwk(InputDate, MonthsToAdd)
    MessageBox.Show(d)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks for all the feedback.
The solution that I was able to parse together is as follows:

- A text box to show the number of months.
- A text box to show the new date.
- A button click action to run the following code:

```
    Private Sub BtnMonth_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnMonth.Click
        Dim WrkDt As Date = Now


        Dim QtyMnths As Integer = CType(TxtMntCount.Text, Int32)
        Dim newFoM = New Date(WrkDt.Year, WrkDt.Month, 1).AddMonths(QtyMnths)
        Dim DoWDt As Integer = WrkDt.DayOfWeek
        Dim newMntdate = newFoM.AddDays(Enumerable.Range(0,
                         Date.DaysInMonth(newFoM.Year, newFoM.Month) - 1).Where(Function(i) newFoM.AddDays(i).DayOfWeek = DoWDt).Skip(1).First())
        TxtNewDate.Text = Format(newMntdate, "MMMM dd, yyyy (ddd)")
    End Sub
```

This works perfectly fine for me!

Mary's solution looks great, and I will give it a shot in the future when I need a modular input.

Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: It’s always a good idea to verify your results, I used dotnetfiddle to basically write a unit test, where I verify correctness by adding zero months and  comparing the input to the result.  If your algorithm produced the correct result, all results should be true:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/dBstyU

Answer (score 0):

I tested your solution, and it doesn’t produce the described results.

See test and correct solution at: https://dotnetfiddle.net/v5wGng

A couple of things from your original problem, you should prefer calculation to loops wherever possible, and you should use the required types wherever possible.  If you have date in one format (string) and need it in another for your calculations, you should do the conversion and then call a function that does your calculations where all of the parameters are of the correct type.

```
    Public Function GetSameWeekAndWeekDay(dt as date, months as integer) as Date
        Dim newMonth =(new date(dt.year, dt.month, 1)).AddMonths(Months)
        Dim week = getweek(dt)
        Dim sameWeekDay = GetNthDayOfWeek(newMonth, week, dt.DayOfWeek)
        Return SameWeekday
    End Function

    Public Function GetWeek(dt as date) as integer
        Return(dt.day - 1) \ 7
    End Function

    Public Function GetNthDayOfWeek(dt as date, week as integer, weekDay as System.DayofWeek) as Date
        Dim first = new Date(dt.year, dt.month, 1)
        Dim baseDate = first.AddDays(-(first.DayOfWeek - system.dayofweek.Sunday))
        Dim newDate = baseDate.AddDays((week * 7) + weekday)
        If(newdate.DayOfWeek < first.DayOfWeek) then
            newDate = newDate.AddDays(7)
        End If

        Return newdate
    End Function
```